# IntelliJ (Access is denied)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, access-denied

My professor had us upgrade from the community version of IntelliJ to the ultimate version, as well as begin using JDK 9.0 versus 1.8 and start using Scenebuilder. When I try to build my code though I keep getting the (Access is denied) error. When I try to open up the

"C:\Users\USERNAME.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\compile-server\pt_2_868f9741\mappings"

folder in file explorer, access is denied. I have tried taking ownership of the folder, but I do not have permission to make any changes to it. The same problem is popping up when I run older programs that worked earlier in the semester as well.

I have already tried uninstalling IntelliJ and running a disk cleanup, then reinstalling but the problem still comes up.

Any ideas as to what went wrong or how to fix? 
I am running Windows 10 , which I have heard has been having a few issues with access and ownership, etc, and am the only user on the laptop.

When I restart my computer, the first time I try building a project this error actually pops up first and then every time after that, the error further below appears.

```
Error:Internal error: can't save module index: C:\Users\Eric Gonzalez\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\compile-server\pt_2_868f9741\jigsaw\module-info.map (Access is denied)
```

This is the error message:

```
`Error:Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) C:\Users\USERNAME\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\compile-server\pt_2_868f9741\mappings\strings.tab (Access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\USERNAME\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\compile-server\pt_2_868f9741\mappings\strings.tab (Access is denied)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:343)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resizeFile(PagedFileStorage.java:355)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resize(PagedFileStorage.java:338)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.<init>(ResizeableMappedFile.java:60)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:82)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:74)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:38)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:53)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.DependencyContext.<init>(DependencyContext.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.Mappings.createImplementation(Mappings.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.Mappings.<init>(Mappings.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildDataManager.<init>(BuildDataManager.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:267)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

I have also just found a similar problem in running Unity. In trying to build a project in Unity I receive the message

```
Creating directory Library/SceiptAssemblies failed.
Please ensure there is enough disk space and you have
permissions setup correctly.
```

And again intrying to acces the folder, i get the same problems as I did with IntelliJ.

Comment: Did you try running it in `Run as Administrator` mode?

Comment: What antivirus do you use?

Comment: You should ask your System Administrator for help. There is nothing you can do if you have no permission.

Comment: Running IntelliJ? I hadn't , but the error is still coming up when I do

Comment: And MacAfee is the default antivirus and I get popups that my trial ended, but I am using WebRoot

Comment: if you have any antivirus installed?  add exception for the
    said folder
Run IntelliJ as admin

Comment: `Run as Administrator` worked for me

Comment: No, you should never need to run your IDE as Administrator. This is an ugly workaround. You should try to discover the true cause of the problem and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having access denied as output, please try to change the project or file path in any of the local disk except Local Disk C;, it worked for me.